# PHP output in a JavaScript expression

Tags: php, javascript, html

Please consider the following scenario with a simple HTML document and a JavaScript loaded in it:

```
<!-- doc.html -->
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>        
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
</html>

// script.js
window.onload = function()
{
    var d = new Date();
    d.setHours(<?php echo(date("H")); ?>);
}
```

It's really Quite simple, isn't it?
However, while this coode works perfectly for getting the current hour (which will be returned as an `INT`), it doesn't if I try to receive a more complex date/time format like the one below:

```
var serverTime = <?php echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); ?>;
```

This should encode to `1900-01-01 00:00:00`. So, cause this is not a legal expression I want to encapsulate the result with quotes:

```
var serverTime = "<?php echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); ?>";
```

At a first glance this should work. Unfortunately, it doesn't. `serverTime` contains just an empty string.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What gets returned when you just do `echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s");` in PHP?

Comment: Nothing. It should work fine.

Comment: Don't know why this wouldn't work, but to set a time in javascript I'd use `var d = Date(); d.setTime(<?php echo time() * 1000; ?>);`

Comment: @Sascha by the way. that original code would **not** encode to `1900-01-01 00:00:00`, it would show the current time and date. PHP's date does **not** even go back that far!

Comment: Putting PHP code in JS file ? should that work ? or file name must have extension like .php to have php working ?

Comment: Is a bit confusing what you put at the top that the name of your file is doc.html and not a php script.

Comment: it worked for me !!
http://km-basicresearch.com/t/test.php  
`var serverTime = "<?php echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); ?>";`

Comment: @Chris - Using `d.SetTime()` leads to an error: "`setTime` is not a function".

Comment: @UnLoCo - Firebug says: "missing ; before statement".

Comment: @SaschaHoll Sorry that should be `var d = new Date();`

Comment: @Chris - Yeah, already figured out. But it returns 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe your Timezone isnt correctly setup

try

```
<?
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
?>
```

or similar  - full list can be found here

http://de3.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

Comment: Finally figured it out. `script.js` needs to be renamed to `script.php` and the default timezone must be set.

Answer (score 0):

There is **no** reason why `var serverTime = "<?php echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); ?>";` shouldn't return something like:

```
var serverTime = "2011-05-12 05:12:56";
```

Check to make sure that `echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s");` is working correctly.

Other than that, the code **should work fine**.

See here: http://codepad.org/3CNx1ch9
Output: http://codepad.org/3CNx1ch9#output

Comment: So, that's why I can't understand it!

Comment: Dreamweaver reports a syntax error on the line `var serverTime ...`.

Comment: @SaschaHoll what does that mean? Did you try it in a browser?

Comment: Yeah, Firebug says: "missing ; before statement"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5403/discussion-between-neal-and-sascha-holl)

Answer (score 0):

The javascript won't execute your php code.
Think of it like this:
When the page is rendered php "replaces your php code" with the output of the php code.

So basically this

```
var serverTime = '<?php echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); ?>';
```

Should be rendered as

```
var serverTime = '2011-11-28 xx:xx:xx';
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are wrong in the way of you insert your parameters. Acording to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setHours) I think you should do this:

```
// script.js
window.onload = function()
{
    var d = new Date('<?php echo(date("F d, Y H:i:s")); ?>');
    d.setHours(<?php echo(date("H")); ?>, <?php echo(date("i")); ?>, <?php echo(date("s")); ?>);    
}
```

The statment `var d = new Date('<?php echo(date("F d, Y H:i:s")); ?>');` is to follow the example of [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate).

Because I can't see why php will fail to send the result of the `date()` function.

Comment: Using single quotation marks results in a String containing the PHP code.

Comment: @SaschaHoll I think all of these code are in a php script, so the quotes doesn't matter at the moment in you open the `<?php ?>` tags.

Answer (score -1):

Try using single quotes:

```
var serverTime = '<?php echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); ?>';
```

Comment: single quotes or double quotes should not matter in this case.

Comment: I wasn't sure if nested quotes were confusing the PHP parser (unlikely I know)

Answer (score -1):

Because you are using double quotes in your JavaScript you need to use single quotes in your php.

```
var serverTime = "<?php echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); ?>";
```

Comment: See comment on the answer below. the quotes should not matter. They are in two different contexts.

Comment: Why does that make a difference? The PHP should be processed before the javascript.